Адаптивные элементы декора для фото
Пытаюсь реализовать задачу по добавление элементов декора для фото (два круга за фото). Удалось расположить их правильно, но они абсолютно не адаптивные. При уменьшении экрана пропорционально уменьшается только фото. А элементы декора абсолютно не управляемы.
Как разрешить данную проблему с элементами декора чтобы при уменьшении экрана они пропорционально уменьшались с фото.



.advertisement__crisper {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: flex-start;
     justify-content: center;
}
 .crisper__content-row {
     display: flex;
     width: 100%;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: space-between;
     row-gap: toRem(20);
     column-gap: toRem(40);
}
 .content-row__box-items {
     flex: 0 0 67%;
     position: relative;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
}
 .content-row__box-items::before {
     position: absolute;
     content: "";
     aspect-ratio: 1;
     max-width: 694px;
     min-height: 694px;
     border-radius: 100%;
     opacity: 0.2;
     background: var(--decodeSmallCardAbout);
     z-index: -1;
     padding: 0 170px;
}
 .content-row__box-items::after {
     position: absolute;
     content: "";
     max-width: 862px;
     min-height: 862px;
     aspect-ratio: 1;
     border-radius: 100%;
     opacity: 0.1;
     background: red;
     z-index: 2;
     padding: 0 180px;
}
 .content-row__inner-cell {
     position: relative;
     display: block;
     aspect-ratio: 1;
     max-width: toRem(549);
     z-index: 3;
     border-radius: 100%;
}
 .content-row__pic-circle {
     overflow: hidden;
     border-radius: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     object-fit: cover;
     object-position: center;
}
 .content-row__desc-textbox {
     flex: 0 0 27%;
}
 .content-row__title-our {
     color: #311f09;
     font-family: var(--fonFamilyTinos);
     font-size: 80px;
     font-size: toRem(80);
     line-height: 1.1;
}
 .content-row__word {
     color: #ff8a00;
     font-family: var(--fonFamilyTinos);
     font-size: toRem(80);
     font-weight: 700;
     line-height: 1.1;
}
<div class="crisper__content-row content-row">
  <div class="content-row__box-items">
    <div class="content-row__inner-cell">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/C8hS4ru.png" alt="Order" class="content-row__pic-circle" width="549" height="549">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-row__desc-textbox">
    <h2 class="content-row__title-our"><strong class="content-row__word">Our</strong> restautant</h2>
    <div class="content-row__box-paragraph">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



SCSS:


//!BEM-Block
.advertisement {
  // .advertisement__crisper
  &__crisper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

//!BEM-Block
.crisper {
  // .crisper__content-row
  &__content-row {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    // flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    row-gap: toRem(20);
    column-gap: toRem(40);
  }
}

//!BEM-Block
.content-row {
  // .content-row__box-items
  &__box-items {
    flex: 0 0 67%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    &::before {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      aspect-ratio: 694 / 694;
      max-width: 694px;
      min-height: 694px;
      border-radius: 100%;
      opacity: 0.2;
      background: var(--decodeSmallCardAbout);
      z-index: -1;
      padding: 0 170px;
    }
    &::after {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      max-width: 862px;
      min-height: 862px;
      aspect-ratio: 862 / 862;
      border-radius: 100%;
      opacity: 0.1;
      background: red;
      z-index: 2;
      padding: 0 180px;
    }
  }
  // .content-row__inner-cell
  &__inner-cell {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    aspect-ratio: 549 / 549;
    max-width: toRem(549);
    z-index: 3;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
  // .content-row__pic-circle
  &__pic-circle {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
  }
  // .content-row__desc-textbox
  &__desc-textbox {
    flex: 0 0 27%;
  }
  // .content-row__title-our
  &__title-our {
    color: #311f09;
    font-family: var(--fonFamilyTinos);
    font-size: 80px;
    font-size: toRem(80);
    line-height: 1.1;
  }
  // .content-row__word
  &__word {
    color: #ff8a00;
    font-family: var(--fonFamilyTinos);
    font-size: toRem(80);
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.1;
  }
}




а обязательно их делать отдельными элементами? может пусть будут частью картинки? всмысле тега img: img{border: 10% solid #aaa; outline: 5vmin solid #ddd}

Слишком много всего и лишнего для реализации этих кругов.
В идеале это делать через box-shadow:


body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden auto;
  margin: 0;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow:
    0 0 0 20px rgba(150,150,150, .2),
    0 0 0 40px rgba(150,150,150, .2);
}

.image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
<div class="image">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/C8hS4ru.png" />
</div>



Жаль только, что box-shadow не поддерживает значения в процентах.
Это усугубляет решение, если требуется прям автоматический адаптив относительно изображения.
Что ж, используем псевдоэлементы и тут есть даже два варианта:
1. width и height больше родителя:


body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden auto;
  margin: 0;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}

.image::before,
.image::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background-color: rgba(150,150,150, .2);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.image::before {
  width: 120%;
  height: 120%;
}

.image::after {
  width: 140%;
  height: 140%;
}

.image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
<div class="image">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/C8hS4ru.png" />
</div>



2. scale()


body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden auto;
  margin: 0;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}

.image::before,
.image::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background-color: rgba(150,150,150, .2);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.image::before {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.image::after {
  transform: scale(1.4);
}

.image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
<div class="image">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/C8hS4ru.png" />
</div>




Оба этих варианта будут поддерживать динамическое изменение "декора" относительно изображения.
Ниже демка, где можно "подёргать" размер изображения:


const img = document.querySelector('.image');

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  img.style.width = img.style.height = `${300 * event.target.value}px`;
});
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden auto;
  margin: 0;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}

.image::before,
.image::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background-color: rgba(150,150,150, .2);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.image::before {
  width: 120%;
  height: 120%;
}

.image::after {
  width: 140%;
  height: 140%;
}

.image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

input {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 20px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
}
<div class="image">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/C8hS4ru.png" />
</div>

<input type="range" min=".2" value="1" max="1.25" step=".05">



